# Automatically list the contents of a directory when i cd into it only if it's a sub-directory of $HOME

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

From a reddit thread I found this short snippet you can add to your `.bashrc` that automatically shows the list of contents of a dir you've `cd`'d into:

```bash
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

Though this is great but I would like this to be effective only if the folder I've `cd`'d into is a sub-directory of `$HOME`. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following executes the `ls` only if the current directory (after successfully changing it) is the user's home directory, or a subdirectory thereof:

```bash
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@" || return

    case $PWD in
        "$HOME"|"$HOME"/*) ls
    esac
}
```

Alternatively, with a `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` test in `bash`:

```bash
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@" || return

    if [ "$PWD" = "$HOME" ] || [[ $PWD == "$HOME"/* ]]; then
        ls
    fi
}
```

Alternatively, with an extended globbing pattern in `bash`:

```bash
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@" || return

    if [[ $PWD == @("$HOME"|"$HOME"/*) ]]; then
        ls
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I completely forgot I could use `$PWD` to get the full path, instead I used something like `$(readlink -f $@)` lol.

Comment: Or `[[ "$PWD" != "$OLDPWD" && "$PWD/" = "$HOME"/* ]]`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but that would not evaluate to _true_ for `cd .`, i.e. when the current directory does not change (which I don't know matters to the user in the question).

Comment: I was not suggesting to use that in place of the `|| return`. Just those two things: (1) avoid ls when the current working directory does not change (which I agree may or may not be desirable) (2) simpler way to check that $PWD is or is within $HOME. Ideally we'd also want to check using canonical paths (like using `realpath`/`readlink -f`) as it's not uncommon for home directory paths to have symlink components in enterprise environment at least.